# Backbone relationship between the view and the router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I believe that in the data-driven programming paradigm, the router and the view should be isolated from each other, and they communicate to each other only through model changes, which they both subscribe to.

However, the various tutorials online all do this differently. I have seen code that instantiates a view inside the router's initialize method, and hence giving the router a way to access the view. I have also seen code that passes the router to the view, so that the view can listen on the changes on the router's route events.

I don't believe either approach is right, as it breaks the separation of concern. As I am new to Backbone, can someone more experienced and knowledgable confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem using the Router to instantiate Views, actually is the way I use to work. The Router detects a new URL and *detach* any not used View and *instantiate* the requested ones.

Passing the Router reference to the View can be uglier, not to say too much effort to keep the reference traveling between Views and SubViews.

But in the other hand Views have to be able to send signals to the Router to change the *navigation* so I also go for the easy way and make the Router globally visible for all elements in my App and I can call `App.router.navigate()` from any View without having to remember to pass the reference explicitly. This decision can be defended because only one Router instance is allowed in any Backbone application.

Comment: Thanks! A few comments:
1) instead of App.router.navigate, you can use Backbone.history.navigate. From the Backbone source code, I believe that is the intention of making Backbone.history a global instance.

Comment: 2) I believe that in most Backbone code I see, having the router instantiate the view is the most common approach. However, I believe this is non-ideal, as it couples the view with the router unnecessarily.

Comment: 3) I have been quite successful in getting the views and the router to communicate via changes in models, and this is an approach that completely decouples the two. I think this is the backbone way, but I don't see enough of it in practice, hence the question.

Comment: How do you want to have a Model being the communication channel when there are still not any Model instantiate?. What I mean is not only that the Router instantiates the needed Views for each route but also all the Collections and Models, even _fetching_ them and then plugging the Collections and Models with the Views. Is after that moment when Router moves out of the scene and let Collections, Models and Views to comunicate with each other through events. Router for me in the _setting-up_ tool.

Answer (score 0):

In some projects I have used a global event dispatcher, which passes the routing events to the views.

```
window.Dispatcher = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

In the router you can bind to `'all'` event which captures `route:*` events:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.bind('all', this.onRoute);
},
onRoute: function(route) {
      Dispatcher.trigger(route);
}
```

In your views you can bind to Dispatcher events and react to route changes:

```
initialize: function() {
    Dispatcher.on('route:index', this.onIndex, this)
}
```

This is similar to having a model that changes when the route changes, but I feel this is easier to manage, and also doesn't require passing the router to views. Not sure if this is the right way to do it, but then again Backbone enables you to do things in many different ways.

Comment: I also was thinking in this but you just move the communication dependency from the _Router_ to the new _Dispatcher_ element. I like the _EventAggregator_ pattern but in this case I see it like another unnecessary layer. And in the other hand _who has instantiate the View in the first place?_